# Remove element in data doesn't refresh keys in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to make a list of items that provides an input and a color picker. It should always have an empty element at the end of the list.

Elements are populated with objects that are stored in `data`.

Everything is OK, I do a simple method that filters objects with empty value, then add a new one.

But, when the user set empty value on an element that is not the last one:

- the "data" values is well ordered, empty value is removed
- but the view keeps the "key", so the elment is still here

This is what I do on the parent Vue:

```
addEmptyElement() {
  // now find any empty values
  this.values = this.values.filter((v) => v.length);
  // and append an empty one
  this.values.push("");
},
```

And the values are use to bind Item component like this:

```
<Item
  v-for="(v, i) in values"
  :key="i"
  v-bind:text="v"
  @valueChanged="onItemChanged"
/>
```

The "valueChanged" event is emitted by Item and provides the position in the list and value that chaged.

I created a simpler example that you can check here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-component-order-problem-rc4o1?file=/src/App.vue

To give some precision:

- The "Element" component "emit" value changes, so the parent knows which element changed
- I use `this.$.vnode.key` to have find the value to change in parent vue (that's maybe where there is a problem)

Maybe I did it wrong, with a bad implementation, so please, tell me what I badly do :)

Thanks !

Comment: The final empty item represents an unsaved new item? How about giving that it’s own markup to avoid confusing the list of *existing* items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you see has more to do with this paragraph in [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#maintaining-state)

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with `v-for`, by default it uses an "in-place patch" strategy. If the order of the data items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the order of the items, Vue will patch each element in-place and make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular index.

> This default mode is efficient, but **only suitable when your list render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM state (e.g. form input values).**

This why using simple *index* in `v-for` as a `key` is tricky. It's much better to not rely on index and maintain your own unique `id` even it's a bit more work...

Also the usage of `this.$.vnode.key` smells...it is not a documented API so you should definitely avoid it and just pass an `id` by a prop explicitly

[working exaple](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-component-order-problem-forked-jdjnv)

### ...other thought

Just after I posted my answer I realized one more thing ...so just to be complete:

This can easily work with `v-for` `index` as a key. The reason why it didn't worked for you is in your `<Item>` component. You pass a `text` prop to your Item component. You use the value of the prop for **one time initialization of** the `value` in the `data` and use the `value` as `v-model` for the `input`.

What happens when the list is re-rendered ? Vue updates the `text` prop for each item in the list, but that update **has no effect on the internal component's `value` used as `v-model`** (so it has no effect on the value displayed in the `<input>` element)!!

Solution is to rewrite `Item` component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="model" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["modelValue"],
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue;
      },
      set(evt) {
        this.$emit("update:modelValue", evt);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

...and change the `App.vue`:

```html
<Item
    v-for="(v, i) in values"
    :key="i"
    :modelValue="v"
    @update:modelValue="onItemChanged(i, $event)"
  />
```

And it **just works** with the rest of the code unchanged - [2nd example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-component-order-problem-forked-r9l0k)

Comment: OK, my example was too simple, in my real application there are IDs and I hadn't thought of doing it this way. React polluted my mind, I was on the wrong track. But your code is just perfect, thank you very much!